# Advanced Task Manager Application for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, task-management

I am looking for a (preferably free) task manager application that is more robust than the default Task Manager that ships with Windows 7.

Functionality I am looking for:

- Alter Security Levels
- Suspend processes (and resume)
- Ability to identify unknown tasks ("what is boblovesdata.exe?!?!?")
- Identify files being accessed by certain processes (you can't delete that it is in use!!!)
- Speeds for Read/Write

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), part of the Sysinternals suite, does everything you want.

- Alter priority levels simply by right-clicking on the process and selecting a priority level.
- Suspend/resume processes by right-clicking, and selecting suspend/resume.
- See what the process does/is by looking at the columns in the program next to the processes. If that doesn't work, right-click and select Search Online, which will search for the program in Google.
- Identify what program is using a specific file by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, to bring up this box:

  [image: Search window in Process Explorer]
  Then simply type in what file you want to see what process is using, and after it searches, you'll see something like this, with the process name, PID, name, and other data:

  [image]
- See the read/write information, either by right-clicking the process and selecting properties, or adding an "IO" category to the view. To my knowledge you can't see exact read/write speeds.

It's a little old, but it still runs well and has a good number of features. Here's what it looks like in normal use:

[image]

Comment: `Process Hacker` is essentially the next version of this tool.

Comment: Ill take a look at it, waiting to see what other options are out there as well.

Comment: IIRC, Process Explorer can also be set up to _replace_ the default task manager, eg. when using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Esc` key combination.

Comment: @BrianS Yeah, there's an option for that in one of the menus.

Answer (score 8):

I also like [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) on Sourceforge which is an open source and very advanced task manager. Pretty much ***the*** open source implementation of SysInternals Process Explorer. The interface is a little different, but pretty much the same idea as ProcExp.

I have even used it for recovery on a munged Windows 7/32 Ultimate system so broken SysInternals Process Explorer would not run (along with lots of other things).

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer - most specifically go over the requirements identified in the question and say does it meet or not etc. (For *bonus points* do it in the same format as the OP and for ***extra** bonus points* include workarounds or suggestions for things that it doesn't do)