# Task manager with logging feature

Tags: windows-7, email, logs, task-management

(This might be answered in the question [Advanced Task Manager Application for Win7](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/advanced-task-manager-application-for-win7), but I'm not sure.)

Is there some sort of program like the task manager with logging/e-mailing capabilities?

Say I want to track the memory consumption of a particular program over time and I'd like to set an interval in which it will send me an email with the current stats - or perhaps an interval in which it will save the stats to a log file which I can later access and read.

Comment: Is it okay if it just logs without sending an email?

Comment: Yeah, sure thing!

Answer (score 3):

[Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/) has options to log processes that have been launched, and statistics on process duration and average CPU use when they exit, but it doesn't have ability to email the log or log the memory consumption. You could share the log folder over dropbox so you would have access to log.